# save model output in pytorch

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

```
dic = [] 
for step, batch in tqdm(enumerate(train_dataloader)):
inpt = batch[0].to(device)
msks = batch[1].to(device)
#Run the sentences through the model
outputs = model_obj(inpt, msks)
dic.append( {
    'hidden_states': outputs[2],
    'pooled_output': outputs[1]})
```

I want to save the model output in each iteration but I got the below error for a small set of datasets.
**RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory.**
notice that without the below code my model works correctly.

`dic.append( { 'hidden_states': outputs[2], 'pooled_output': outputs[1]})`

How can I save these outputs in each iteration?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should always post the full error stacktrace. Secondly, you should move the outputs from your GPU when you want to store them to free up memory:

```py
dic.append( {
    'hidden_states': outputs[2].detach().cpu().tolist(),
    'pooled_output': outputs[1].detach().cpu().tolist()
})
```