# API Rest with several models loaded using GPU but not at same time

Tags: python, flask, gpu, flask-restful, huggingface-transformers

I am creating an API Rest (using Flask) that does inference with several huggingface transformer models (using pipelines and custom fine-tuned models).

The problem is that all the models don’t fit at GPU at the same time.

Is there a way of loading a model into GPU make inference with that model and move it to CPU and load next model to GPU for inference then to CPU.

I have tried that moving the model from "cuda" to and from "cpu" each time the the model gets a call, the problem is that it does not delete the predicted variable after running the model, it keeps memory in use and when I load other model cuda memory error is thrown!

Comment: Do you really to that much data that you need a GPU for interference? You can easily move a model to CPU the same way to moved it to GPU.

Comment: I have tried that approach, the problem is that I don’t delete predicted variable after running the model, it keeps memory in use and when I load other model cuda memory error is thrown!

Comment: You have to move these variables to CPU as well. Maybe you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67195895/save-model-output-in-pytorch/67196153#67196153).